# VHDL: is correct to use don't care?

Tags: case, vhdl

I am learning VHDL and for the university I've to write an encoder with priority with different describing styles like DataFlow, Behavioural, etc... The problem is when I have to describe it using statements like "case..when".

The base solution would be something like this:

```
architecture Behav_arch of encoderw_priority
begin

    case req is
        when "1000" | "1001" | "1010" | "1011" | "1100" | "1101" | "1110" | "1111" =>
            code <= "11";
        when "0100" | "0101" | "0110" | "0111" | "0100" | "0101" | "0110" | "0111" =>
            code <= "10";
        .....

    end case;           

end Behav_arch;
```

but I proposed this solution, that I think it's more readable:

```
entity encoderw_priority is
    port(
        req: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        code: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        active: out std_logic
    );
end encoderw_priority;

architecture Behav_Case of encoderw_priority is
begin

    process(req)
    begin

        case req is
            when "1---" =>
                code <= "11";
            when "01--" =>
                code <= "10";
            when "001-" =>
                code <= "01";
            when "0001" | "0000" =>
                code <= "00";
            when others =>
                code <= "XX";
         end case;
    
         case req is
            when "0000" =>
                active <= '0';
            when others =>
                active <= '1';
         end case;

    end process;

end Behav_Case;
```

Is this a correct solution? Simulating this, it works correctly. But I don't know if during synth or implementation it can bring some problems.

Thank you

Comment: **Simulating this, it works correctly.**  Unfortunately [not in a manner useful as a priority encoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPnUA.jpg). It should do so in a matching case statement (-2008, `case ?` in both places). See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.9 Case statement,  Also see Annex G Guide to use of standard packages, G.2 Using the STD_LOGIC_1164 package, G.2.9 Modeling with don’t care’s. There's no guarantee a particular synthesis vendor supports matching case statements for a particular target. Another alternative might be an if statement which naturally priority encodes and can be synthesized.

Comment: An if statement is [an easy alternative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwznk.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

The classic and easiest solution to this is an "if" statement.   I looked at the code referenced by @user1155120 and found it a little more complex than required.

```
    if req(3) = '1' then 
            code <= "11";
    elsif req(2) = '1' then 
            code <= "10";
    elsif req(1) = '1' then 
            code <= "01";
    else 
            code <= "00";
    end if;
```

Certainly case? will also work, but it is VHDL-2008 and you are at the whims of your synthesis vendor for support:

```
    case? req is
        when "1---" =>
            code <= "11";
        when "01--" =>
            code <= "10";
        when "001-" =>
            code <= "01";
        when "0001" | "0000" =>
            code <= "00";
        when others =>
            code <= "XX";
     end case?;
```

@EML injected some FUD about driving assigning an 'X' in an assignment in general and in particular here, the others branch of a case statement.   @EML was expressing concern about VHDL based on Verilog - which are significantly different in how they handle 'X'.

First conclusions:  Assigning 'X' is the correct thing to do.  However, when assigning '-' then some of @EML's concerns apply.

General notes:  In VHDL, there are three senses of X: 'U', 'X', and '-'.

'U' is intended to be uninitialized.  For it to have this meaning, only the simulator is to assign this value (initial value during elaboration).  So do not use 'U' in an assignment.

'X' is intended to be an invalid value that results from multiple opposing drivers, however, due to historical reasons, for synthesis 'X', also means don't care when it is assigned to an object (signal, variable, or constant).

'-' is intended to mean don't care.  However, with ordinary relationals (=, /=) and regular case statements, it did not have this meaning.   VHDL-2008 added matching relationals (?= and ?/=) as well as case? and these understand understand '-' as don't care.

It should be noted that neither the matching relationals nor the case? treat 'X' as don't care - Only synthesis tools only treat 'X' as don't care when it is assigned to an object.

So why should I use 'X' and not '-' for conveying don't care in an assignment?  It all comes down to what happens next to that object (signal, ...).   For an 'X', if the object is used in the select expression of case? or in a matching relational, the 'X' will never be misunderstood as don't care and will only match when compared with a '-' (in the target of the case? or other argument of a matching relational).  Hence, correct behavior is always achieved.

On the other hand, if a '-' is assigned to an object, the analysis gets more interesting.   For matching relationals, in simulation, the '-' will incorrectly be understood as a don't care and may result in a mismatch between simulation and synthesis results - this is bad.   For case?, a '-' in the expression that follows the case? results in a run time error during simulation.   For ordinary relationals (= and /=) and case (without the ?), '-' only matches '-', so there are no hazards using when assigning a '-' to an object.

It is good to see that VHDL has continued in its tradition of robust language design.  Yea for VHDL.  I am sure glad I don't use Verilog.  While VHDL presents a challenge with respect to strong typing, strong typing protects us from doing bad things.  Verilog OTOH has many lessons to learn that are subtle and easy to accidentally do.  Thanks for the lively discussion @EML.

Comment: Note that `code` is assigned `XX` in the default branch - not a good idea for code which is to be synthesised.

Comment: @EML  Do you know of any synthesis tool that treats "XX" any different than "--"?   I have yet to see any.   In fact, older tools had to support 'X' as '-' since '-' did not exist in types with less then 9 values (such as MVL7).   The only place where I have found it useful to differentiate 'X' from '-' is in behavioral code for modeling in testbenches.

Comment: Don't know, never tried it. My point is that you can't leave the synth to make up it's own mind on what to do, since you'll then get a sim mismatch between the RTL and post-synthesis netlist, as per my answer.

Comment: @EML  Within the case? statement all the conditions that have either 1 or a 0 are specified in the case targets before the others. Hence the others only covers meta values (U, X, Z - also W, L, H if bad design practices are followed) .  Here, a metavalue in, results in X out.   Shows up in simulation as RED.   Hence, this usage of 'X' or '-' is a good one.   In fact, we would say that the if-then-elsif-... solution masks 'X's which can lead to hidden issues - such as flip-flops that were not properly reset.

Comment: In the real world you don't do waveform displays; you do regression runs, of hundreds or thousands of tests, hence no red. The issue arises if you have a feature or bug that causes the RTL code to propagate X's, which the post-synth netlist won't do. In this case, you get a sim mismatch, and an equivalence failure even without the bug. It's common to have Verilog guidelines that tell you not to use `casex` or `casez` in synthesisable code - why? Unless you really know what you're doing (not the case with the OP), follow the guidelines, don't use `X` in synthesisable code.

Comment: @EML  In VHDL RTL it is common to use '-' and 'X' in assignments interchangeably and with out issue.   Are you reading from some published guidelines?

Comment: @EML Just looked at the paper you quoted below.  Your comment/guideline above contradicts it.   In 7.1.3, it explicitly says, For case statements:  a) Always add a default line (to avoid X-Latching)  b)  Only use the default to assign X’s (to avoid X-Optimism).   Wow.   That is exactly what is being done here.   Hence, even the guidelines you quote support the code I wrote above and not your claim.

Comment: @EML reponding to your comments below, You are expounding on Verilog rules that don't apply to VHDL. In Verilog, 'X' can mean don't care to both the synthesis tool and the simulator. In VHDL, assigning a value to 'X' only means don't care to the synthesis tool and never any other tool that understands the semantics of the language. An X on the input of "=" only matches 'X' and on "?=" only returns '1' when compared with '-', otherwise returns 'X' (or 'U') . Thanks for sharing another reason I am glad I don't use Verilog.

Answer (score 1):

1 - a 'better' solution might be to simply do a K-map reduction on the required values for `req`. Your choices seem to be closely related for each branch, so the logic is likely to be minimal. The synthesiser will produce exactly the same result, but you might consider an if-else with simple logic to be 'better' in some way

2 - your `case` doesn't work; it matches against the `std_logic` `-` enumeration, and not against a 'real' don't-care. Of course, you won't have any of these in synthesis, and you're unlikely to have them in simulation, so the conditions will never match

3 - your `case` also assigns `X` to `code`. You mustn't ever do anything like this in synthesis. If the synthesiser treats this as a don't care and chooses some value to assign to `code` then you'll get synthesis and simulation mismatches. This is a difficult area - see Mike Turpin's [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.5387&rep=rep1&type=pdf), for example, or various SNUG Verilog papers

4 - your `case` should be a `case?`, as pointed out by user1155120. `case?` is designed for this sort of thing, and is an improved version of Verilog's `casex/z`, but I would think twice before using it. The comparison operation is complex (see the `?=` table on p122 of the LRM), and unless you're careful, you could get simulation and synthesis mismatches. I would be inclined to stick with the original solution (which is more readable anyway, and easier to change).

Comment: Your case 3 contradicts the paper you use to support it.   In the paper it says:   In 7.1.3 it says, For case statements:  a) Always add a default line (to avoid X-Latching) b) Only use the default to assign X’s (to avoid X-Optimism).

Comment: Turpin (who I used to work with) is *not* recommending X-semantics in 7.1.3. He's saying *if* you use X-semantics, you can increase pessimism with an X assignment in a case. The other paper that is normally quoted in this context is Sutherland's ('I'm still in love with my X'). Sutherland's view (10.3 X-assignment guidelines) is *not* to do this, and instead to use assertions to detect X (*and*, if you do use X-assignment in a `case`, to use synthesis pragmas to stop the synth seeing them). All this is way too complicated for the OP, so my advice was simple - don't do it. (continued...)

Comment: @JimLewis Your advice, OTOH, was simply to use X-assignment with no understanding of the consequences, which is hardly helpful for a beginner. If you want to use X semantics, you have to have an entire methodology for dealing with optimism and pessimism, you have to set up your linter to make sure that X assignments aren't reachable, and so on.

Comment: You are expounding on Verilog rules that don't apply to VHDL.   In Verilog, 'X' can mean don't care to both the synthesis tool and the simulator.   In VHDL, assigning a value to 'X' only means don't care to the synthesis tool and never any other tool that understands the semantics of the language.   An X on the input of "=" only matches 'X' and on "?=" only returns '1' when compared with '-', otherwise returns 'X' (or 'U') .   Thanks for sharing another reason I am glad I don't use Verilog.

Comment: WRT #4, there is no reason to "think twice" with VHDL's case?.   Like the ordinary case, case? it is an error if more than one case alternative can match a given value.   Furthermore, it is an error if the case expression contains a '-'.   Error means either the compiler or the simulator is required to detect the issue.

Comment: thanks for the lively discussion, per your suggestion I added a discussion about assigning 'X' in VHDL - note however, the conclusion is that it is always ok - so the discussion only needed to be added due to your concerns (FUD).   Please read the updated post before assuming that I don't understand your issues.   You realize we know each other through email right?

Comment: @JimLewis - sure - since at least 1076.6, going on 20 years ago. I gave up on that after Bhasker let slip who was pulling the strings. The 'FUD' is, I think, rather unfair. We simply have different priorities - I'm more concerned with the end-to-end process, whereas you're understandably more concerned with pure language concerns. In this case, yes, X assignment makes a lot of sense if your only concern is writing 'good' VHDL. But, IMHO, X assignment is a can of worms that needs to be approached with great care if you're more concerned with getting an expensive chip out of the door.

Comment: It is not just this example.   In VHDL, an 'X' assignment as a don't care never causes issues (again in VHDL and not so in Verilog).   So 'X' assignment in VHDL is never a can of worms.   Also what I learned here is that '-' should never be used as don't care in an assignment.   Ironically, I learned before std_logic_1164 and never switched from assigning 'X' to '-' - lucky me.    You have also made an occasional appearance in the 1076 WG in which I am active.